# XHTML validator that supports HTML5 elements

Tags: validation, xhtml-1.0-strict, xhtml, html

I'm developing HTML5 documents and need to validate them, but all validators I find seem to support either XHTML 1.0 Strict or HTML5. Is there any validator that validates XML wellformedness and also supports HTML5 elements?

Comment: Bear in mind that the HTML5 validators determine, for documents at the end of a URL, whether to treat the document as XHTML or not, the same way that browsers do, i.e. by means of the mime type. So to get them to check for XML wellformedness, serve the document to the validator as `application/xhtml+xml`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an XHTML 5 validator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669660/is-there-an-xhtml-5-validator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [(X)HTML5 validator](http://html5.validator.nu/). By nature of it's name it should take into consideration all HTML5 elements.

Answer (score 2):

One validator is the W3 one found at...

http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_uri+with_options

Comment: I will provide HTML from direct input. Which option must I set for it to validate XML wellformedness?